# Jquery event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made this Jquery event and want to apply opacity on my button but it's not working.Please help!

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-opacity" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Sign-Up
</button>
```

```css
button#btn-opacity {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: hidden;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-opacity').mouseenter(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `button` is visible and you try to fade it in. See https://jsfiddle.net/ss6pq5L0/

Comment: Did you import the jquery file or cdn ?\

Comment: I want to apply opacity effect on my button @PranavCBalan

Comment: @AishaSalman use `animation()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn-opacity').mouseenter(function(event) {
          /* Act on the event */
          $(this).css('opacity', 0.3);
        });
        $('#btn-opacity').mouseleave(function(event) {
          /* Act on the event */
          $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        });
      });
```

```css
button#btn-opacity {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: hidden;
}
button {
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn-opacity" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Sign-Up
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by teuta might work but just in case you want a simple css code for this event try this:

```
#btn-opacity:hover{
    opacity:0.3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) but I want to achieve this by Jquery @Shrikanth Buds